# Bottle set Authorization header on redirection

Tags: python, http-headers, bottle, http-redirect

I have a Python/Bottle server application, a Seaweed media server, and an NGINX web server.
I need to check the client's permission before allowing shim to download a file.
So:

1. User requests to download a file.
2. Backend checks user permission. If granted, redirects it to the file location.

But the problem is that the Seaweed secured by JWT and an Authorization header must be set.

***Can I set Authorization header and then redirect user?***

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set headers on redirects. Here's one way to do it in Bottle:

```
@route(...)
def handler():
    # after you've authorized the user, set your auth header:
    response.set_header('Your-auth-header', auth_token)

    # perform the redirect
    response.status = 302
    response.body = ''
    response.set_header('Location', file_location)
    raise response
```

(That's off the top of my head; not tested code.)